# AWS ec2 time zone reflecting wrong in java app

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, timezone

I am running my application on EC2 Instance i did the configuration setting for date and time zone and it is resulting me me IST as desired.
But when i am running my java application it showing me Time Zone as EDT.

Could you please tell me why i am getting two different Time Zone in java application and date command in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that your code somewhere calls [`TimeZone.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault%28java.util.TimeZone%29).  You can try calling this passing a different time zone, or passing `null` to reset the time zone to the system's default time zone.

It also may simply be that you need to restart your EC2 instance, as the default time zone is read when the JVM is first started.  If you've changed it afterwards, you won't see the effect until restarting the JVM.

In general though - it's not a good practice to rely on the time zone setting of the operating system.  Consider explicitly setting time zones where needed, or intentionally using `TimeZone.setDefault` in your code.